# Android SQLite: FROM and LIMIT values flipped while compiling

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-limit

My app has a top level menu in a RecyclerView and clicking any item opens a new activity with a submenu in a new RecyclerView. Menu item titles are stored in 'tableL1' of an SQLite database, and submenu items in 'tableL2' in a column headed 'titlesL2'. To get the correct tableL2 row numbers for any set of titles making up a submenu, I have a column in tableL1 headed 'rowrefs', each entry comprising an offset and a limit (eg "0,15" to skip none and take the first 15). On clicking a top level menu item, these row references are stored in SharedPreferences, from where they are read by the second activity as the submenu RecyclerView is initiated.

I'm using the sqliteassethelper explained here https://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html
 and the first version of the app worked fine using the following query in DatabaseAccess.java: `String qL2Titles = "SELECT titleL2 **FROM "+listTable+" LIMIT "+rowRefs**;  (listTable is 'tableL2' and rowrefs might be '0,15')`.
 I'm now rebuilding with androidx but this same query now causes a crash, the logcat giving this error message:

> "Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "0": syntax
>   error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT titleL2 **FROM
>   0,15 LIMIT tableL2**"

So it seems to have flipped the table id and rowrefs fields 'while compiling'. I checked my code carefully to check that I hadn't flipped these fields somehow but could find no way that could happen, and as I say the first version worked fine. I researched the error message and found nothing identical but similar error messages were apparently not very specific and helpful. Before smashing something in exasperation I tried one crazy thing - to flip the values in my request like this: `String qL2Titles = "SELECT titleL2 FROM "+rowRefs+" LIMIT "+listTable;` - which appears to make no sense but hey, the app now works fine like this. So I could move forward, but I am nervous to do this as I don't like a line in my app which seems like nonsense. Can it always be trusted to compile in this counter intuitive way? Anyone seen anything similar before or can suggest why this is happening?

From onBindViewHolder in the top level menu adapter:

```
holder.menuListItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.englishdreaming.appily", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                title = mTitles.get(position);
                listTable = mTables.get(position);
                rowRefs = mRowrefs.get(position);

                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("title", title).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("listTable", listTable).apply();
                sharedPreferences.edit().putString("rowRefs", rowRefs).apply();

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on"+mTitles.get(position));

                Intent intentA = new Intent(mContext, PhrasesMenuL2Activity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intentA);

            }
        });
```

Strangely, this works:

```
public ArrayList<String> getL2Titles() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences("com.englishdreaming.appily", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String rowRefs = sharedPreferences.getString("rowRefs", "");
        String listTable = sharedPreferences.getString("listTable", "");

        String qL2Titles = "SELECT titleL2 FROM "+rowRefs+" LIMIT "+listTable;

        ArrayList<String> mL2Titles = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(qL2Titles, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            mL2Titles.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return mL2Titles;
    }
```

(Edit in response to comment by Tim Biegeleisen)

The ArrayLists 'mRowrefs' and 'mTables' are filled by calling two DatabaseAccess methods in initRecyclerView() in the first activity:

```
public void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: initRecyclerView called");

            DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
            databaseAccess.open();
            ArrayList<String> mTitles = databaseAccess.getL1Titles();
            ArrayList<String> mTitleTranss = databaseAccess.getL1TitleTranss();
            ArrayList<String> mRowrefs = databaseAccess.getRowrefs();
            ArrayList<String> mTables = databaseAccess.getTables();
            databaseAccess.close();

            for (int n = 0; n < mTitles.size(); n++) {
                System.out.println(mTitles.get(n));
            }

            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            PhraseMenuAdapter adapter = new PhraseMenuAdapter(this, mTitles, mTitleTranss, mImages, mRowrefs, mTables);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
```

and these look like this:

```
String qTables = "SELECT table_id FROM tableL1";
String qRowrefs = "SELECT rowrefs FROM tableL1";

public ArrayList<String> getRowrefs() {

        ArrayList<String> mRowrefs = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(qRowrefs, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            mRowrefs.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return mRowrefs;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTables() {

        ArrayList<String> mTables = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(qTables, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            mTables.add(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return mTables;
    }
```

My database seems to have the columns correctly headed:

[database snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6avt.jpg)

Comment: The obvious explanation would be that you are storing `rowRefs` and `listTable` backwards.  Check the code where you are writing these to shared preferences.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I'm sure I'm not. I've added more code above - I don't see any error, and the code worked as expected in the first version of the app.